# How to increment a value of the table cells?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I can't understand how to increment a value of the table cells like: 1,2,3 etc?

My code:

```
$('#table').each(function(i){
    $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text(i);
});
```

Please, look at the [full example](http://jsfiddle.net/rJYpR/2/).

Comment: Choose the best answer by clicking on the **tick mark** on the left of the corresponding answer.

Comment: @OP go through your posts and accept the answer which you feel to be useful

Comment: @Algorithm - Go to your questions and drill down. On left side of every answer, below that upvote and downvote, you will see a watermarked tickmark. Click on that will make it green and it means you accept an answer.

Comment: @Algorithm  may be this helps http://yfrog.com/m926515323j

Comment: Thanks for the example, I just discovered jsfiddle.net. It's a cool site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/H6c7V/1/) is what you want:

```
var i = 1;
$('#table').find('td:nth-child(1)').each(function()
                                         {
                                             $(this).text(i++);
                                         });
```

Or [simpler](http://jsfiddle.net/H6c7V/2/):

```
$('#table').find('td:nth-child(1)').each(function(i)
                                         {
                                             $(this).text(i + 1);
                                         });
```

Comment: if `function(i)` is used then no need to increment `i`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#table tr td:first-child').each(function(i){
    $(this).text(i+1);
});
```